# Count unreaded Number of missed call and message in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, message, phone-call

How to display badge of unread message and call in windows phone 8 application?

I want display notification count in my application icon when I open application at that time it will remove like call and message application.

I know the tile notification but i don't know how remove badge when I open application

**Note:** how to send and receive toast notification with badge

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution...

[Handle tile pragmatically in windows phone.](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Working_with_Live_Tiles_in_Windows_Phone_7)

```
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
            if (null != tile)
            {
                // create a new data for tile
                StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
                 tile foreground data
                data.Title = "";
                data.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/IconicTileMediumLarge.png", UriKind.Relative);
                data.Count = 0;
                 to make tile flip add data to background also
                data.BackTitle = "Secret text here";
                data.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/Green.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
                data.BackContent = "Back Content Text here...";
                 update tile
                tile.Update(data);
```

Comment: This does not answer how to retrieve missed calls count.