# Query toast notifications on WP8.1

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone-8.1

My WP8.1 App creates toast notifications that will appear - like SMSs - in the Notification center of the Windows Phone (this part works like a charm).

In one precise scenario, I would like to limit the number of notifications my app can have in the Notification Center at a given time:

> *"if a user has 3 notifications displayed, he cannot add another until he clears one of them"*.

Any idea how to hook into the notification center to know its state?

Thanks!

Comment: have you had a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566310/count-unreaded-number-of-missed-call-and-message-in-windows-phone)

Comment: Does the [ToastNotificatioHistory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory.aspx) API help with this at all?

Comment: Thanks but none of those will work. @Petesh, the GetHistory() method is only available with Win10.

Comment: That's a shame. The API is not particularly granular :(